# MySQL - How to delete only one register of a group?

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I have one or more registers as a result of a select and i need to delete one of them....
How to do that?

DELETE FROM xxx WHERE `id` ***[[1 of]]***
(SELECT `id` FROM xxx WHERE `usuario_id`=1 AND `disco_id`=1)

Comment: You could use `LIMIT`

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE 
  FROM xxx 
 WHERE usario_id=1 
   AND disco_id=1
 LIMIT 1
```

**N.B.** This will remove an undetermined row that matches the conditions.

If you wish to select which is deleted you can use `ORDER BY`, e.g delete oldest created record:

```
  DELETE 
    FROM xxx 
   WHERE usario_id=1 
     AND disco_id=1
ORDER BY created_temporal_field ASC /* Or an auto_incremented id */  
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Note that in the absence of an ORDER BY clause LIMIT is a fairly meaningless, and a bit dangerous.

Comment: @Strawberry Fairly meaningless? It LIMITs the delete to 1 undetermined row that matches the conditions.. exactly what the OP asked for. Way less dangerous than not having a LIMIT, in fact I regularly add LIMIT 1 to delete statements that I only expect to target 1 row.

Comment: Yeah, but *which* one? If the answer is "it doesn't matter" then that's sometimes symptomatic of more serious problems concerning data integrity.

Comment: @Strawberry From the OP it looks like the answer is "it doesn't matter". I don't think I should get a down vote for answering the question.. but your 2nd comment is indeed valid.

Comment: @Strawberry I have qualified the answer.

Comment: I have never received a downvote with which I agreed ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry Haha, fair enough.. I have received a few warranted ones however! I feel I have now clarified this question enough to mitigate yours though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
DELETE FROM xxx WHERE id =(SELECT id FROM xxx WHERE usuario_id=1 AND disco_id=1 order by id desc limit 1)
```

You have one or more registers as a result of a select and you want delete one of them. Just researching one row throught `limit` like has the code above.

Comment: This post has been automatically flagged as »low quality», because you didn't provide an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to this situation. I have explained the way they thought most appropriate. Thanks and sorry

Comment: @nalply I don't believe an explanation is required when an attempted query and detail of what is expected is provided.. this is a simple syntax correction.

Comment: Don't tell me. I didn't flag the post. It's an automatic process on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Normally TOP 1 is a good idea.

SELECT TOP 1 will mean the table scan stops as soon as the one item is found.

```
DELETE FROM xxx WHERE id =(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM xxx WHERE usuario_id=1 AND disco_id=1)
```